# data.frame behaving differently when using complete.cases in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering why the *First* approach works OK but the *Second* approach fails? Is there anyway to make the output of Second approach to become like the First approach:

```
#First:

data <- mtcars["wt"]
d <- scale(data)
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- c(d)
data

#Secondt:

data <- mtcars["wt"]
data <- data[complete.cases(data), ]  ## THIS LINE is the only difference with ABOVE ##
d <- scale(data)
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- c(d)
data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only have one column, you need to do:

```
data <- mtcars["wt"]
data <- data[complete.cases(data), , drop = FALSE]  ## THIS LINE is the only difference with ABOVE ##
d <- scale(data)
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- c(d)
data
```

Otherwise:

```
data <- mtcars["wt"]
data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
str(data)
# num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
```

You have a vector